# Can I create (an how to) a single html link to a mobile app, that sends the user to itunes or gplay based on device?

Tags: android, html, ios, hyperlink

as for the title.

I have to place a simple link to an app on a website. The app has 2 versions, ios and android, so I should put 2 links, one to itunes and the other to gplay. ok.

Is there a way to create a single link that will send the user to the proper store?

Comment: Use firebase dynamic link.

Comment: where will be redirected user, who opens your site from a desktop?

Comment: there will be no link on desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase dynamic links is one way. I would like to recommend [Branch.io](https://branch.io), they do the same but more efficiently and the links that are generated don't look like spam. I did a huge study comparing both and found Branch to be better.

One cool thing, they even handle [desktop deep linking](https://docs.branch.io/pages/web/text-me-the-app/) i.e. they enable users to send the app link as an SMS from a custom designed page that gets loaded if they click the link on a desktop machine.

Answer (score 3):

User `Firebase Dynamic Links` which are match for your scenario.

**As per firebase documentation:**

> With Dynamic Links, your users get the best available experience for
>   the platform they open your link on. If a user opens a Dynamic Link on
>   iOS or Android, they can be taken directly to the linked content in
>   your native app. If a user opens the same Dynamic Link in a desktop
>   browser, they can be taken to the equivalent content on your website.

**Source:** https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links

Comment: Plus one for Firebase dynamic links.

Comment: mmm, as far as I can see, thosa are links to app internals. I just want to send the user to the app download page on istore or gplay, that's all.

Comment: Yes, you can implement it with firebase. If app already installed then link will open app or redirect to istore or gplay.